# Why do I get an Invalid Syntax from print in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, syntax-error

So I'm fairly new to programming and I'm just paying around trying to make some programs. This one is self-explanatory, but why do I get an invalid syntax for 'print' in line 12 (the first 'elif' statement)?

```
while True:
    temp = raw_input("Would you like to convert:\nCelsius to Fahrenheit (press 1)\nor\nFahrenheit to Celsius (press 2)\n")

    if temp == 1:
        celsius = raw_input("What is the temperature in degrees Celsius?")
        tempFahr = ((int(celsius)*(9/5))+32)
        print "When it is " + celsius + " degrees celsius, it is " + tempFahr + "degrees fahrenheit."

    elif temp == 2:
        fahrenheit = raw_input("What is the temperature in degrees Fahrenheit?")
        tempCel = ((int(fahrenheit)-32)*(5/9)
        print "When it is " + fahrenheit + " degrees fahrenheit, it is " + tempCel + "degress celsius."

    elif temp = 42:
        print "You're a winner!"

    else:
        print "That is not a valid option."

    print "Press 'enter' to input another value"

    raw_input()
```

Also, if I over complicated something, I would really appreciate if you could point out what it was. Try not to correct me too much, though, I would like to try and figure it out on my own.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: But the question is tagged with python-2.7 ...

Comment: @MartinR good point well made...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two syntax errors.  First, you forgot a closing `)` in the `tempCel` line, which confuses Python about the next `print`:

```
    tempCel = ((int(fahrenheit)-32)*(5/9)
    print "When it is " + fahrenheit + " degrees fahrenheit, it is " + tempCel + "degress celsius."
```

Then you used `=` where you meant `==`:

```
elif temp = 42:
```

There are other errors -- for example, you're comparing `temp`, which is a string, to `1` and `2`, which are integers, and you also might want to type `5/9` at the console to see what it gives you -- but they're not `SyntaxError`s.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'm going to fix the rest now. I still need to train myself to spot errors like that.

Comment: Also thanks for pointing out the floating point problem. Those are a pain in the butt.

Answer (score 0):

you should try

```
        print("When it is " + str(fahrenheit) + " degrees fahrenheit, it is " + str(tempCel) + " degress celsius.")
```